# Change value in XML tag using XSLT according to the attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xalan

I am new to XSL and I am stuck with a problem.

I have an xml of the following format:

```
<Destinations>
    <conf:Destination id="12">
        <conf:attributes>
            <conf:attribute1>1212</conf:attribute1>
        </conf:attributes>
    </conf:Destination>
    <conf:Destination id="31">
        <conf:attributes>
            <conf:attribute1>3131</conf:attribute1>
        </conf:attributes>
    </conf:Destination>
</Destinations>
```

And say, I have an xsl with following 2 params:

```
<xsl:param name="attribute12" select="'21'" />
<xsl:param name="attribute31" select="'5'" />
```

I want to have a xsl template in XSLT 1 that changes my xml as follows:
1) For destination id=12 in xml, value inside 'conf:attribute1' tag to be set as 21
2) For destination id=31 in xml, value inside 'conf:attribute1' tag to be set as 5

This way I will have final xml as:

```
<Destinations>
    <conf:Destination id="12">
        <conf:attributes>
            <conf:attribute1>21</conf:attribute1>
        </conf:attributes>
    </conf:Destination>
    <conf:Destination id="31">
        <conf:attributes>
            <conf:attribute1>5</conf:attribute1>
        </conf:attributes>
    </conf:Destination>
</Destinations>
```

Can anybody please help.

Comment: Why is the question tagged as `xslt-2.0` when asking for XSLT 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the identity transformation template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and then two templates

```
<xsl:template match="conf:Destination[@id='12']/conf:attributes/conf:attribute1">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="$attribute12"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="conf:Destination[@id='31']/conf:attributes/conf:attribute1">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="$attribute31"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```